# How to replace object in JSONB array with matching value(s)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have some nested JSONB object/arrays that I want to update/insert into array completely when a given set of values match.

I've tried this command `UPDATE asset SET detail = jsonb_set(detail, '{"date": "01/01/2019"}', '{"name": "ABC", "date": "01/01/2019"}');`, but doesn't work since the command is looking for an index and using `||` simply appends the new object into the array instead of replacing it.

## Schemas

### Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE asset (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(),
    detail jsonb NULL,
    events_connected jsonb NULL
);
```

### JSONB Schemas

```
[{
  "name": "Stackoverflow",
  "date": "01/01/2019"
}]
```

A little more in depth

```
[{
  "id": "12345",
  "events": [{"type": 0, "date": "01/01/01", "ratio": 1.0}]
}]
```

### EDIT:

I've played around with this code which almost works, but it updates all rows with the new object instead of simply inserting/updating the event id and keys that matches. The sub query that finds the matching params seem to work.

```
update 
    asset
set
    events_connected = 
        jsonb_set(
            events_connected,
            array[elem_index::text, 'events', nested_elem_index::text],
            '{"type": 2, "ratio": 5.0, "tax": 1, "date": "01/02/2019"}'::jsonb,
            true)
from (
    select
        (pos - 1) as "elem_index",
        (pos2 - 1) as "nested_elem_index",
        elem->>'id' as "id"
    from
        asset,
        jsonb_array_elements(events_connected) with ordinality arr(elem, pos),
        jsonb_array_elements(elem->'events') with ordinality arr2(elem2, pos2)
    WHERE
        elem->>'id' = '12345' AND
        elem2->>'type' = '1' AND
        elem2->>'date' = '01/02/2019'
) sub
WHERE
sub."elem_index" IS NOT NULL AND sub."nested_elem_index" IS NOT NULL;
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1b3f3b0c7a9f0adda50c54011880b61d

Comment: What do mean with "incoming detail"? Are you doing an INSERT? If so, why are you trying to UPDATE? The only difference between in and out is the array braces? So you simply want to put all data into an array?

Comment: Well both would be the case. So INSERT ... ON CONFLICT(...) UPDATE SET. I'm trying to avoid duplicate data being inserted by using key values. Like `type`, or `date` inside the object.

Comment: So think of it this way. You have a array of objects that have user ids. To avoid duplicate data. You simply update the object in the array to avoid duplication. If the user id doesn't exist, you append the object to the list.

Comment: This would be so easy with a properly normalized data model. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: For your edit: I would be extremely useful to add some sample data (what is in the table already? What comes in?) and the result you are expecting. Maybe a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6f0805e2607b0e4e71b6f9a667cc9e3c could help in this case

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Yes I have a good feeling simply using a basic table to store this time of information would make life a breeze from a read and manipulation standpoint, but the person who made this choice seemed to be married to it. Reason I'm asking for help with this.

S-Man: Added. Hopefully that adds a little more context to my issue?